# Is there a "not equal" operator in Python?

Tags: python, comparison, operators, comparison-operators

How would you say "does not equal"?

```py
if hi == hi:
    print "hi"
elif hi (does not equal) bye:
    print "no hi"
```

Is there something similar to `==` that means "not equal"?

Comment: Are you asking about `else`, `!=` (optionally `<>`) or `is not`?

Comment: Attention that <> doesn't work any more in python 3, so use !=

Comment: from python documentation:
`Python3 : The operators <, >, ==, >=, <=, and != compare the values of two objects.`
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons

Comment: from python documentation:  `python2: `
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Answer (score 689, accepted):

Use `!=`. See [comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). For comparing object identities, you can use the keyword `is` and its negation `is not`.

e.g.

```
1 == 1 #  -> True
1 != 1 #  -> False
[] is [] #-> False (distinct objects)
a = b = []; a is b # -> True (same object)
```

Comment: How would you compare two binary data?

Comment: Just some info, PEP401 mentioned in the comments was an April Fool joke. `<>` is not supported in Python3 now.

Comment: Just for the record: [Comparison operators in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/release/3.7.4/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Did not know that you can compare binary data. I thought that objects are the most you can compare.

Answer (score 70):

Not equal  `!=`  (vs equal `==`)

Are you asking about something like this?

```
answer = 'hi'

if answer == 'hi':     # equal
   print "hi"
elif answer != 'hi':   # not equal
   print "no hi"
```

This [Python - Basic Operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm) chart might be helpful.

Answer (score 32):

There's the `!=` (not equal) operator that returns `True` when two values differ, though be careful with the types because `"1" != 1`. This will always return True and `"1" == 1` will always return False, since the types differ. Python is dynamically, but strongly typed, and other statically typed languages would complain about comparing different types.

There's also the `else` clause:

```
# This will always print either "hi" or "no hi" unless something unforeseen happens.
if hi == "hi":     # The variable hi is being compared to the string "hi", strings are immutable in Python, so you could use the 'is' operator.
    print "hi"     # If indeed it is the string "hi" then print "hi"
else:              # hi and "hi" are not the same
    print "no hi"
```

The `is` operator is the *object identity* operator used to check if two objects in fact are the same:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [1, 2]
print a == b # This will print True since they have the same values
print a is b # This will print False since they are different objects.
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use both `!=` or `<>`.

However, note that `!=` is preferred where `<>` is deprecated.

Comment: `<>` no longer exists in Python 3, you can only use `!=`.

Comment: From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211270/is-there-a-difference-between-and-operators-in-python#comment67686660_40211270): *"`<>` is [deprecated and removed in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060506/is-there-a-not-equal-operator-in-python)."*

Answer (score 7):

Seeing as everyone else has already listed most of the other ways to say not equal I will just add:

```
if not (1) == (1): # This will eval true then false
    # (ie: 1 == 1 is true but the opposite(not) is false)
    print "the world is ending" # This will only run on a if true
elif (1+1) != (2): #second if
    print "the world is ending"
    # This will only run if the first if is false and the second if is true
else: # this will only run if the if both if's are false
    print "you are good for another day"
```

in this case it is simple switching the check of positive == (true) to negative and vise versa...

Answer (score 1):

The standard `operator` module holds `ne` method which is a wrapper for `!=` a.k.a. not equal operator.

```py
import operator
operator.ne(1, 1)   # False
operator.ne(1, 3)   # True
```

This is especially useful if you need to make comparisons in a setting where a function is expected.

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 2, 3, 3]
list(map(operator.ne, a, b))  # [True, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two operators in Python for the "not equal" condition -

a.) != If values of the two operands are not equal, then the condition becomes true.
    (a != b) is true.

b.) <> If values of the two operands are not equal, then the condition becomes true.
    (a <> b) is true. This is similar to the != operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "is not" for "not equal" or "!=". Please see the example below:

```
a = 2
if a == 2:
   print("true")
else:
   print("false")
```

The above code will print "true" as a = 2 assigned before the "if" condition. Now please see the code below for "not equal"

```
a = 2
if a is not 3:
   print("not equal")
else:
   print("equal")
```

The above code will print "not equal" as a = 2 as assigned earlier.

Comment: Note that `is not` won't work for string comparison

Comment: This answer is simply wrong; `is` and `is not` do not test equality, they test identity.

Comment: @kaya3, please help me to understand why "is not" will not work for my example.

Comment: I suggest you read this other Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `!=` operator to check for inequality.

Moreover in [Python 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_2) there was `<>` operator which used to do the same thing, but it has been **deprecated** in Python 3.

Comment: From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211270/is-there-a-difference-between-and-operators-in-python#comment67686660_40211270): *"`<>` is [deprecated and removed in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060506/is-there-a-not-equal-operator-in-python)."*

Answer (score -3):

Use `!=` or `<>`. Both stands for not equal.

The comparison operators `<>` and `!=` are alternate spellings of the same operator. `!=` is the preferred spelling; `<>` is obsolescent. (Reference: Python language reference)

Comment: You may *[link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42448590/edit)* to that reference, preferably with page anchors. But ************** ***without*** ************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Comment: From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211270/is-there-a-difference-between-and-operators-in-python#comment67686660_40211270): *"`<>` is [deprecated and removed in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060506/is-there-a-not-equal-operator-in-python)."*