# Python Test for Full List

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list in Python. The list has 5 elements, which can either be "None" or any other string. I want to test if each element is not "None" (that is if all the elements are set).

I've written the following code (where `userInventory` is the 5-element list) :

```
 if all(item is not None for item in userInventory):
   print = "Inventory is full, you rat!"
 else:
   ...
```

For example, `['None', 'Monkey', 'None', 'Jewel', 'None']` should go to the else statement, while `['None', 'None','None','None','None']` should display the message. But right now, the if statement returns true for all the lists...

**NOTE** The list comes from an HTML form parsed by the cgi library. The data was initially placed by Python and appear like this in HTML : `<input type="hidden" name="Inventory1" value="None">`

```
userInventory=[form.getvalue("Inventory1"),form.getvalue("Inventory2"),form.getvalu    e("Inventory3"),form.getvalue("Inventory4"),form.getvalue("Inventory5")]
```

Comment: I am not sure... If I print the list, it appears as 'None' and I am pretty sure that it's the string "None" and not the null value None.

Comment: Where is the `'None'` string coming from? `None != 'None'`. That would explain why your code is not working.

Comment: I added a note to explain. I tried with both None and 'None' but neither worked. That's surprising because it works in python interactive.

Comment: After your edit: Then just change your code to `all(item is not 'None'...`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `item != 'None'` is better.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Ah, yes of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is` is used for identity check. Since your list contains string `'None'` instead of `None`, you need to use `!=`:

```
item != 'None'
```

Related: [Python `is` operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/python-is-operator)

Comment: This worked, thanks. I am new to Python. I though `is not` was syntactic sugar for `!=`. I'll read about 'identity check'!