# Difference between "is" and "isinstance" in python

Tags: python

For the following code, `str` is variable of unicode type but

```
str is unicode            # returns false
isinstance(str, unicode)  # returns true
```

Why `is` is return false?

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-python-is-operator should give you a better perspective. `is` is checking for object equality.

Comment: @karthikr `s/equality/identity/`

Answer (score 14):

`is` operator is used to check if both the objects are one and the same, whereas `isinstance` is used to check if the second parameter appears anywhere in the inheritance chain of the first parameter.

So, when you do something like this

```
print(u"s" is unicode)
```

you are actually checking if `u"s"` is the `unicode`, but when you do

```
print(isinstance(u"s", unicode))
```

you are checking if `u"s"` is of type `unicode` and the latter is actually `True`.