# How to print "correct" after user answers something correctly in python version 3.4.3

Tags: python

This is my current code it prints two random numbers between 1 and 20 and asks the user to add them together. I want it to say correct when the answer has been answered correctly, but I am not to sure how to do this.

The program runs fine it will work but when the user enters the correct answer nothing happens.

```
from random import randint


def Add(x, y):

    return x + y


num1 = randint(1,20)
num2 = randint(1,20)
print(num1, "+", num2)
answer = input("What is the answer to the question: ")

if ("answer") is (num1 + num2):
    print("Correct")
```

Comment: Are you running python2.x or python 3.x? The input() function changed between these versions.

Comment: I am using python 3.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast `input` to an int, use the actual **variable** *answer* and don't use [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator) to test equality, is should be used to check *identity*, and will fail for numbers > 256 in your case:

```
num1 = randint(1,20)
num2 = randint(1,20)
print(num1, "+", num2)
answer = int(input("What is the answer to the question: "))

if  answer ==  num1 + num2:
    print("Correct")
```

Why is should not be used:

```
In [35]: i = 256

In [36]: j = 256

In [37]:  i is j
Out[37]: True

In [38]: i = 257

In [39]: j = 257

In [40]:  i is j
Out[40]: False
```

The only reason i is j is True for 256 is because python *caches* small ints from -5 to 256.

Comment: Thank you this cleared it up but do you know how I would go about making it say "Inncorrect" if the answer is wrong I can't seem to us an else.

Comment: @elitereece,adding which? `num1 + num2` is adding the two random numbers

Comment: Yea I edited the comment. I'm new to this site pressed enter and it saved.

Comment: I mean it says correct when you get the right answer but I'm not to sure how to make it say incorrect when you get the answer wrong.

Comment: `else:print("You suck at math")`

Comment: if answer == (num1 + num2):
        print("Correct"), else:print("Incorrect")

So it should fit in like this?

Comment: yes but no comma and the else is at the same indentation as the if on the following line

Answer (score 2):

You put answer in quotations which means that the program is expecting the string "answer" instead of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your last line. I used your Add() function just because you defined it.

```
from random import randint


def Add(x, y):

    return x + y


num1 = randint(1,20)
num2 = randint(1,20)
print(num1, "+", num2)
answer = input("What is the answer to the question: ")

if int(answer) == Add(num1 , num2):
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```