# How to verify entry data with a text file in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to make a basic program that when someone enters data into an Entry box, it checks to see if it matches data in a text file. This is the code that I have but whenever I press the button to activate the function nothing happens, no error, nothing. I have been searching online and in stackoverflow all night long, please help. :(

```
    if login_form is 1:
        frame_2.destroy()
        label_2 = Label(frame_1, text="Username")
        label_3 = Label(frame_1, text="Password")
        label_1 = Label(frame_1, text="Name")
        svalue = StringVar()
        svalue_1 = StringVar()
        svalue_2 = StringVar()
        entry_1 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue)
        entry_2 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_1)
        entry_3 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_2)
        label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        label_3.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
        entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        entry_3.grid(row=2, column=1)

        def check():
            directory = r'C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\PycharmProjects\Learning\UserList\%s' % svalue.get()
            os.chdir(directory)
            fr = open(svalue.get(), 'r')
            text = fr.readlines()
            username = svalue_1.get()
            password = svalue_2.get()
            if username is text[0] and password is text[1]:
                print("...")
            else:
                print("...")

        button_1 = Button(text="Login", fg="blue", command=check)
        button_1.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: are your sure that login_form is 1?  You don't have some other button showing that you are mistaking for button_1, do you?

Comment: This is only a chunk of the code, my main problem is the IF statement inside the function CHECK, for whatever reason SVALUE.GET() isn't working with the statement. And I don't know why.

Comment: What happens if you add `print username`

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is that svalue is defined outside of the check function

Comment: I need it to do something else, not print, and no I ran so many tests to make sure it wasn't anything like that. I tried using different loops and functions and they all worked. I need the IF statement to work but that is the only one that doesn't.

Comment: You should use `==` instead of `is`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that `is` does not do what you think it does. It doesn't verify that two strings are equal, it verifies that two variables point to the same object. The `if` statement in your code will never be true since the values you are trying to compare are different objects (read: two distinct local variables)

You have a further problem that the data you get from the file via `readlines` will have newlines in the data, but the data from the widget will not. You should strip off the newlines before doing the compare.

You need to change this:

```
if username is text[0] and password is text[1]
```

... to this:

```
if username == text[0].strip() and password == text[1].strip()
```

For more information about the `is` operator you can read the answers for the question [Understanding Python's "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13650293/7432)

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, I have been stuck on that for almost 24 hours!