# Comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object

Tags: python, numpy

Apparantly it will (in the 'future') not be possible anymore to use the following:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([0,1,2]) == None
> False
> FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
```

This also breaks the lazy loading pattern for numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
def f(a=None):
    if a == None: 
        a = <some default value>
    <function body>
```

What other possibilities allow you to still use lazy initialization?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You are looking for `is`:

```
if a is None:
    a = something else
```

The problem is that, by using the `==` operator, if the input element `a` is a numpy array, numpy will try to perform an element wise comparison and tell you that you cannot compare it.

For `a` a numpy array, `a == None` gives error, `np.all(a == None)` doesn't (but does not do what you expect). Instead `a is None` will work regardless the data type of `a`.

Comment: so from a Java point of view, the `is` is considered as a reference check whereas the `==` is considered as an `equals()` check (that could be overriden and if not overriden it's just a reference check)

Comment: @Matthias Exactly. From a java point of view, the python's `==` would trigger java's `.equals`, which in `numpy` is overrided to perform a *element-wise check*. Python's `is` would be equivalent to check for reference in java (similar to using `==` with strings). However, for strings in python (i.e. `a = 'hello'; b = 'hello'`), the `a is b` would still return true, as both of them are the same constant (`'hello'`).

Comment: @Matthias have a look [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator), for further detail of the `is` operator.

Comment: the last comparison will be true in Java as well (or is VM dependent?)

Comment: @Matthias to be honest, it's been a long time without programming in Java, so it might be haha. Just wanted to point out the behaviour in python =P