# Python--when are two variables tied to the same object?

Tags: python

```
x, y = 1.1, 1.1
a = 1.1
b = 1.1
print(id(x), id(y), id(a), id(b))
print(x is y, a is b)
```

I would think that x, y, a, and b would all be tied to the same object/memory location. Does declaring two variables in a single line have something to do with this?

Output:

```
31705096 54184744 31705048 31705048
False True
```

Comment: I do not see any chained assignment in the question. If you mark as duplicate the minimum standard should be to link something that actually answers the question.

Comment: @PaulPanzer - Sorry. It's been a very long day, and nine times out of ten the "this isn't a duplicate" is due to failure to inspect the linked answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834770/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-floats might help.