# float identity comparison in Python lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, floating-point, comparison, identity

Why does the following happen with Python's lambdas (in both Python 2 and 3)?

```
>>> zero = lambda n: n is 0
>>> zero(0)
True
>>> zero = lambda n: n is 0.0
>>> zero(0.0)
False
```

Comment: this does not have to do with `lambda`s. This has to do with [floating point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and integer caching (`256` is the last integer that returns `True`!)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I don't think this relates to floating point arithmetic, it's simply float caching vs integer caching isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['is' operator behaves unexpectedly with floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834770/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-floats)

Comment: To be clear, floats are not cached apparently

Comment: There's almost _never_ an excuse for comparing numbers using `is` instead of `==`. Don't do it, and then you won't see these sorts of surprises. It's an interesting academic exercise to explain what's going on here, but from the point of view of practical programming the question should just never come up.

Answer (score 2):

The most common Python implementation store a number of small integers as "constant" or "permanent" objects in a pre-allocated array: see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong). So, these numbers can be recongized as identical objects using the `is` operator. This is not done for floats.

If you were to compare the numbers using the equality operator `==`, you'd get identical behaviour for ints as well as floats.

Note that `0` is an integer, and `0.0` is a float.

If you were to use a larger integer instead of `0` (for example, changing the lambda to test for `n is 5000`, and also plugging `5000` into the function), it would return `False` again, because the two `5000` numbers would be different objects internally.

---

Some examples for clarity:

```
>>> zero = lambda n: n is 0
>>> zero(0)
True
```

`is` returns `True` here because both instances of `0` are literally the same object internally (which is what `is` checks for).

```
>>> zero = lambda n: n == 0
>>> zero(0)
True
```

`==` returns `True` this time because the two numbers are equal, not necessarily because they are identical objects internally.

```
>>> zero = lambda n: n is 5000
>>> zero(5000)
False
```

This returns `False` because `5000` is too big a number, it no longer fits in the range of numbers that get pre-allocated internally.

```
>>> zero = lambda n: n is 0.0
>>> zero(0.0)
False
```

This returns `False` again because `0.0` is a float, and for floats there isn't any pre-allocating internally like there is for a limited range of integers, so this is actually exactly the same case as above.

```
>>> zero = lambda n: n == 0.0
>>> zero(0.0)
True
```

Using `==` instead of `is` results in comparing the numbers again instead of internal objects, so now we get `True`.