# Behaviour of "is" keyword in python?

Tags: python, function, equals

Why does the code below produce:

```
False
False
False
```

and not: `False True False`

```
def foo(el):
    return (el is 0.0)

seq=[0,0.0,False]
for el in seq:
    print( foo(el) )
```

Comment: I just ran the program and I got "False True False". Could you show the output or reword the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `is` keyword in python is used to *test if two variables refer to the same object.* It returns `True` if the two variable are referring to same object otherwise it returns `False`.

For Example consider the `class` named `A`:

```
class A:
    pass
```

**Case 1:**

```
x = A() #--> create instance of class A
y = A() #--> create instance of class A

>>> x is y
>>> False
```

**Case 2:**

```
x = A() #--> create instance of class A
y = x #--> here y refers to the instance of x
>>> x is y
>>> True
```

Basically two variables refer to same object if they are referring to same memory location. You can check the identities of the variable by using the built in function in python called `id()`, this function returns the identity of the object (address of the object in memory).

- In **Case 1** `id(x)` is not equal to `id(y)` hence `x is y` returns
  `False`.
- In **Case 2** `id(x)` is equal to `id(y)` which implies *both  `x` and `y` refers to the same object inside the memory* hence `x is y` returns
  `True`.

---

*Now coming to your question,*

```
def foo(el):
    return (el is 0.0)
```

In the function `foo` `el is 0.0` returns `False` because each of the two entities `el` and `0.0` refer to different locations inside memory. You can verify this fact by comparing `id(el) == id(0.0)` which returns `False`.

Comment: Ok thanks! Why is the 0.0 the only element where the id is different? If the return statement was --> return (el is 0) or return (el is False), you get True

Comment: Thats because of the internal implementation of python which states **two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.** Eg. if you declare two variable `a = 2` and `b = 2` then in that case `id(a) == id(b)` will return true. but when you declare two variables `a = 2.5` and `b = 2.5` then  `id(a) == id(b)` returns `False` because python compiles them as two different object, its totally based on the internal implementation in python. For more details about the behaviour of floats in python refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38835030/12833166) .