# Weird Behvaiour of is operator python

Tags: python-3.x

If I do the following

```
x = 0
y = 0
print(x is y)
```

I get `True`

The following code

```
x = 0
y = 0.0
print(x is y)
```

outputs `False` which is the expected behavior.

But

```
x = 0.0
y = 0.0
print(x is y)
```

returns `False`. Why does this happen and how to get around it?

My use case is that I need to distinguish 0 and 0.0 from other values in python like False, "", etc which would return True in a x==0 comparison

EDIT:

The linked question in the comments does not answer my question. I need to know how to get around this problem.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834770/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-floats

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['is' operator behaves unexpectedly with floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834770/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-floats)

Comment: yeah, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38835030/11984670)

Comment: It only answers the first part of my question. I need a way to get around this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `type` first and then the values in that case.

Something like this:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> b = 0
>>> c = 0.0
>>> d = 0.0
>>> type(a) is type(b) and a == b
True
>>> type(a) is type(c) and a == c
False
>>> type(c) is type(d) and c == d
True
>>>
```