# Expressions with "== True" and "is True" give different results

Tags: python, pandas, pep8

I have the following [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                           

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([True, False, True])

print("Whole DataFrame:")
print(df)

print("\nFiltered DataFrame:")
print(df[df[0] == True])
```

The output is the following, which I expected:

```
Whole DataFrame:
     0
  0  True
  1  False
  2  True

Filtered DataFrame:
     0
  0  True
  2  True
```

Okay, but the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style seems to be wrong, it says: *E712 comparison to True should be `if cond is True` or `if cond`*. So I changed it to `is True` instead of `== True` but now it fails, the output is:

```
Whole DataFrame:
    0
0   True
1  False
2   True

Filtered DataFrame:
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

What is going on?

Comment: "Okay, but the PEP8 style seems to be wrong, it says: E712 comparison to True should be if cond is True or if cond.". WTF? PEP8 actually says "Yes: `if greeting`, No: `if greeting == True`, Worse `if greeting is True`".

Comment: Isn't `df[df[0]]` preferable in any case?

Comment: @IanS It may be (not as readable IMO), but the question is not about that :^) "What's the difference between a clever man and a wise man? - A clever man gets out of any trouble with flying colors, a wise man doesn't get _into_ it."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The catch here is that in `df[df[0] == True]`, *you are not comparing objects to `True`*.

As the other answers say, `==` is overloaded in `pandas` to produce a `Series` instead of a `bool` as it normally does. `[]` is overloaded, too, to interpret the `Series` and give the filtered result. The code is essentially equivalent to:

```
series = df[0].__eq__(True)
df.__getitem__(series)
```

So, you're *not* violating PEP8 by leaving `==` here.

---

Essentially, `pandas` gives familiar syntax unusual semantics - that is what caused the confusion.

[According to Stroustroup](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf) (sec.3.3.3), operator overloading has been causing trouble due to this ever since its invention (and he had to think hard whether to include it into C++). [Seeing even more abuse of it in C++](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c_family_interview.htm), Gosling ran to the other extreme in Java, banning it completely, and that proved to be exactly that, an extreme.

As a result, modern languages and code tend to have operator overloading but watch closely not to overuse it and for semantics to stay consistent.

Comment: I do not think he recommended to use that. Using `==` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga PyCharm is smart, but not THAT smart :-) This is exactly why every such checker worth its salt has an option to tell it: "Shut up, I know what I am doing."

Answer (score 9):

In python, `is` tests if an object is the same as another.
`==` is defined by a `pandas.Series` to act element-wise, `is` is not.

Because of that, `df[0] is True` compares if `df[0]` and `True` are the same object. The result is `False`, which in turn is equal to `0`, so you get the `0` columns when doing `df[df[0] is True]`

Comment: So, it's basically a bug due to a lack of an overload?

Comment: You cannot overload `is`.

Answer (score 4):

One workaround for not having complaints from linters but still reasonable syntax for sub-setting could be:

```py
s = pd.Series([True] * 10 + [False])

s.loc[s == True]  # bad comparison in Python's eyes
s.loc[s.isin([True])]  # valid comparison, not as ugly as s.__eq__(True)
```

Both also take the same time.

In addition, for dataframes one can use `query`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [True] * 10 + [False],
        list(range(11))],
    index=['T', 'N']).T
df.query("T == True")  # also okay
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in `pandas` comparison only works with `==` and result is `boolean Series`. With `is` output is `False`. More info about [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650309/2901002).

```
print df[0] == True
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool

print df[df[0]]
      0
0  True
2  True

print df[df[0] == True]
      0
0  True
2  True

print df[0] is True
False

print df[df[0] is True]
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Comment: And it's done like that, because `==` may be redefined for custom classes and `is` may not. It's the same case like `SQLAlchemy` where clauses - OP has to either ignore warning or disable it with `noqa` comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is an elaboration on MaxNoe's answer since this was to lengthy to include
in the comments.

As he indicated, `df[0] is True` evaluates to `False`, which is then coerced
to `0` which corresponds to a column name. What is interesting about this is
that if you run

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame([True, False, True])
>>>df[False]
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-62b48754461f> in <module>()
----> 1 df[False]

>>>df[0]
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
>>>df[False]
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

This seems a bit perplexing at first (to me at least) but has to do with how
`pandas` makes use of caching. If you look at how `df[False]` is resolved, it
looks like

```
  /home/matthew/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py(1975)__getitem__()
-> return self._getitem_column(key)
  /home/matthew/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py(1999)_getitem_column()
-> return self._get_item_cache(key)
> /home/matthew/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py(1343)_get_item_cache()
-> res = cache.get(item)
```

Since `cache` is just a regular python `dict`, after running `df[0]` the `cache`
looks like

```
>>>cache
{0: 0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool}
```

so that when we look up `False`, python coerces this to `0`. If we have not
already primed the cache using `df[0]`, then `res` is `None` which triggers a 
`KeyError` on line 1345 of generic.py

```
def _get_item_cache(self, item):
1341            """Return the cached item, item represents a label indexer."""
1342            cache = self._item_cache
1343 ->         res = cache.get(item)
1344            if res is None:
1345                values = self._data.get(item)
```

Comment: this is not really related to the original question any more but very interesting...