# How to check if all values in a dataframe are True

Tags: python, pandas

`pd.DataFrame.all` and `pd.DataFrame.any` convert to `bool` all values and than assert all identities with the keyword `True`. This is ok as long as we are fine with the fact that non-empty lists and strings evaluate to True. However let assume that this is not the case.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([True, 'a']).all().item()
True  # Wrong
```

A workaround is to assert equality with `True`, but a comparison to True does not sound pythonic.

```
>>> (pd.DataFrame([True, 'a']) == True).all().item()
False  # Right
```

Question: can we assert for identity with `True` without using `== True`

Comment: A comparison to True is not unpythonic if you want to assert that a value is equal to True (and not just truthy). In fact, that's exactly what comparisons are for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, I *do not advise this*. Please do not use mixed dtypes inside your dataframe columns - that defeats the purpose of dataframes and they are no more useful than lists and no more performant than loops.

Now, addressing your actual question, *spolier alert*, you can't get over the `==`. But you can hide it using the `eq` function. You may use

```
df.eq(True).all()
```

Or,

```
df.where(df.eq(True), False).all()
```

Note that

```
df.where(df.eq(True), False)

       0
0   True
1  False
```

Which you may find useful if you want to convert non-"True" values to False for any other reason.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there any reason to use `df.where` or did you just include it in your answer for the heck of it?

Comment: @Aran-Fey It is a useful intermediate step if you want to coerce non-"True" values to False for some other reason besides just calling `.all`. Additionally, I wanted to flex my fingers after a good night's sleep ;)

Comment: I've basically stopped to read after the first paragraph and accepted the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I would actually use

```
(pd.DataFrame([True, 'a']) == True).all().item()
```

This way, you're checking for the value of the object, not just checking the "truthy-ness" of it.

This seems perfectly pythonic to me because you're *explicitly* checking for the value of the object, not just whether or not it's a truthy value.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([True]) is True` returns `False`

Comment: You're right. In that case, I would say that my argument still stands where checking `== True` is perfectly pythonic because you're explicitly checking for the value of the object, not the truthy-ness of it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825925/expressions-with-true-and-is-true-give-different-results