# Python: type(i) is int... but i is int = False

Tags: python, numpy, types

I'm quite sure I'm doing something foolish but can't figure out what it is.

```
predict  = fn_abc(data)

In[3]: predict
Out[3]: array([2])
In[4]: type(predict)
Out[4]: numpy.ndarray
```

Now wrapping my fn_abc with `int`

```
predict  = int(fn_abc(data))

In[6]: predict
Out[6]: 2
In[7]: type(predict)
Out[7]: int
In[8]: predict is int
Out[8]: False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have misunderstood the meaning of `is`. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

```
isinstance(predict, int)
```

Answer (score 3):

`predict is int` checks whether the integer has the same identity as the integer type object. It does not. That integer's type, however, is *equal to* the integer type object. Check whether the integer's type is equal to the integer type object.

```
>>> type(2) == int
True
```

You can expand this check to also handle subclasses with the built-in function `isinstance()`:

```
>>> isinstance(2, int)
True
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
```

The second test checks whether `True` is an instance of an integer. Since `bool` is a subclass of `int`, this is accurate. This is useful for user-defined classes - if you have a `Person` class with a `Customer` subclass, `isinstance()` will tell you that a `Customer` object is also a `Person`. However, not all `Person` objects are `Customer` objects, so it is not commutative (as shown below with `bool` and an integer):

```
>>> isinstance(2, bool)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
type(predict) is int
```

**predict** is 2; **is int** checks to see whether the other item is **type 'int'**, but **2** is not a type.

There is also an **isinstance** method that would be even better.