# Method isn't itself?

Tags: python

Why does a class method equal itself, but *isn't* itself?

```
>>> class Test:
...     def test(self): pass
...
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.test == t.test
True
>>> t.test is t.test
False
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Comment: Try `print(id(t.test))` on both sides of the check and you'll see why `is` isn't working

Comment: Interestingly, `print(id(t.test) == id(t.test))` prints `True` on my machine, so that might lead one to suspect that `is` would evaluate to True as well.