# When should I use list.count(0), and how do I to discount the "False" item?

Tags: python, list, count, boolean

`a.count(0)` always returns 11, so what should I do to discount the `False` and return 10?

```
a = ["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]
```

Comment: In Python 3.x True and False are keywords and will always be equal to 1 and 0

Comment: @Praveen You're saying that as if there's no way to distinguish False from 0.

Comment: @Praveen: try `assert False is not 0` out for size. Equal, yes, but the same object, no

Comment: Now I got it.. thanks Rawing and Eric

Comment: No matter what others say to convince me, I think this is a bug. `count` shouldn't have counted False as 0 in the first place.

Comment: @ozgur: Well, it's completely expected according to the language semantics. You can file a bug report if you want, but it'll get closed as not a bug immediately.

Comment: @ozgur: This is consistent with `0 in [False]`, which returns True. Evidently it was decided that list membership should be tested by equality not identity.

Comment: @user2357112 I am well aware of the language semantics but I also think these kind of things can lead to very subtle bugs which can easily slip through.

Comment: @ozgur: The fact that an interaction can lead to bugs doesn't make it a bug, especially when changing it would lead to worse bugs. Trying to special-case this would just lead to even weirder bugs. Python's True and False are numerically equal to 0 and 1. It's much better to be consistent about that than to try to make them sometimes numeric and sometimes not. Similarly, if you tried to make `list.count` care about types, you'd get `[0L].count(0) == 0`, and that'd be far worse than `[False].count(0) == 1`.

Comment: @user2357112 Well, luckily your last example wouldn't matter in python3+ since there'd be only the long type. However we could argue that we might wish to have `[0.0].count(0) == 1`.

Answer (score 13):

Python 2.x interprets `False` as `0` and vice versa. AFAIK even `None` and `""` can be considered `False` in conditions. 
Redefine count as follows:

```
sum(1 for item in a if item == 0 and type(item) == int)
```

or (Thanks to [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404581/when-use-list-count0-how-to-discount-false-item/39404665?noredirect=1#comment66136825_39404665), and [Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404581/when-use-list-count0-how-to-discount-false-item/39404665?noredirect=1#comment66142335_39404665) for their comments):

```
sum(1 for item in a if item == 0 and type(item) is type(0))
```

or as suggested by [ozgur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793428/ozgur) in comments (**which is not recommended and is considered wrong**, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404581/when-use-list-count0-how-to-discount-false-item/39404665?noredirect=1#comment66136825_39404665)), simply:

```
sum(1 for item in a if item is 0)
```

it **may** ([“is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers?noredirect=1&lq=1)) work for *small* primary types, but if your list contains objects, please consider what `is` operator does:

From the documentation for the [`is` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true
>   if and only if x and y are the same object.

More information about `is` operator: [Understanding Python's "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator)

Comment: _"Always"_ is a fabrication - clearly `type(0)` is treated differently to `type(False)`, otherwise your code wouldn't work

Comment: @Eric It's about implicit and explicit type conversion. You are right, `always` is not that accurate, I remove it to make the answer less controversial.

Comment: @ozgur It would work for primary types. For objects, it depends on the programmer that how & what he/she wants to count. I do not suggest it as it may cause undefined behavior.

Comment: It will not count 0.0 == 0.

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi `list.count(0)` counts also 0.0, so I would say yes.

Comment: No, no, no.  **Never** do `if x is 0` (or any integer instead of 0).  It may happen to work, but that's an implementation detail (small integer interning) which doesn't even work for larger numbers.  A conforming implementation is perfectly free to create multiple distinct zero objects and return false for `0 is 0`.  The correct way to check this is `x == 0 and type(x) is int` (note that there's only one `int` class, ever, so it's safe to use `is` here).

Comment: @Kevin You're totally right Kevin. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: @VPfB tune the answer according to your needs. You can use `or` to include floats as well.

Comment: @Kevin I would still keep the `is` solution along with reasons not to use it. So that later readers do not get caught in this pitfall.

Comment: @Kevin Well, you can always do `int = bool`. If you want a 1000% working solution `type(x) is type(0)` works because there is no way to change the type of an integer literal. Also, you can simplify the whole thing using tuple comparisons: `list(map(lambda x: (x, type(x)), sequence).count((0, type(0)))`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: You can always do `type = SomethingCrazy` too, so if you care about correctness in the face of redefined builtins, it'd have to be something like `x.__class__ is (0).__class__`, or `().__class__.__class__(x) is (0).__class__` if you want to catch types that lie about their class through `__class__`.

Answer (score 10):

This can be done with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#index-20) that compares each element to `False`:

```
>>> a = ["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]
>>> sum((x == 0 and x is not False) for x in a)
10
```

This works because `bool` is a subclass of `int` - `False` equals 0 and `True` equals 1.

Answer (score 8):

You need to filter out the Falses yourself.

```
>>> a = ["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]
>>> len([x for x in a if x == 0 and x is not False])
10
```

---

Old answer is CPython specific and it's better to use solutions that work on all Python implementations.

Since **CPython** [keeps a pool of small integer objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers), zero included, you can filter the list with the `is` operator.

This of course shouldn't be used for value comparisons but in this case it works since zeros are what we want to find.

```
>>> a = ["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]
>>> [x for x in a if x is 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> len(_)
10
```

Comment: More specifically, _CPython_ keeps a small pool. I don't believe a conforming python implementation is required to do this.

Comment: Relying on CPython's internal optimization details is a bad idea, especially when it's so easy to write code that doesn't rely on them.

Comment: Small remark: `filter(lambda` is antipattern almost always. Comprehensions works faster in most cases, lambda is too heavy

Answer (score 6):

How about this functional style solution:

```
print zip(a, map(type, a)).count((0, int))
>>> 10
```

Timing this against some of the other answers here, this also seems to be one of the quickest:

```python
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    zip(a, map(type, a)).count((0, int))
print time.time() - t0
>>> 0.275855064392

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    sum(1 for item in a if item == 0 and type(item) == int)
print time.time() - t0
>>> 0.478030204773

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    sum(1 for item in a if item == 0 and type(item) is type(0))
print time.time() - t0
>>> 0.52236700058

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    sum((x==0 and x is not False) for x in a)
print time.time() - t0
>>> 0.450266122818
```

Answer (score 3):

Solving this problem more generally, you could make your own subclass of list:

```
class key_equality_list(list):
    def __init__(self, key, items):
        super(key_equality_list, self).__init__(items)
        self._f = key

    def __contains__(self, x):
        return any(self._f(x) == self._f(item) for item in self)

    def count(self, x):
        return sum(self._f(x) == self._f(item) for item in self)
```

And then define a key function that checks types:

```
type_and_val = lambda x: (x, type(x))
```

So your usage becomes:

```
>>> a = ["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]
>>> a = key_equality_list(type_and_val, a)
>>> a.count(0)
10
>>> a.count(False)
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to first "decorate" the list by adding the types and the count:

```
decorated_seq = list(map(lambda x: (x, type(x)), sequence))
decorated_seq.count((0, type(0)))
```

If you want to have `0 == 0.0` you could do:

```
decorated_seq = list(map(lambda x: (x, isinstance(x, bool)), sequence))
decorated_seq.count((0, False))
```

Which counts all `0`s that are *not* of type `bool` (i.e. `False`s).
In this way you can define what `count` should do in any way you want, at the cost of creating a temporary list.

Answer (score 2):

Since `count` returns the number of items equal to its input, and since `0` is equal to `False` in Python, one way to approach this is to pass in something that is equal to `0` but is not equal to `False`.

Python itself provides no such object, but we can write one:

```
class Zero:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other == 0 and other is not False

print([1, 2, 0, False].count(Zero()))
```

Be aware that there are other things in Python that, like `False`, are equal to `0`. I can think of `0.0`, `decimal.Decimal(0)`, and `fractions.Fraction(0,1)`. Furthermore, anybody can subclass `int` to create other "fake 0 values", just like `False`. The code above counts all of these, treating `False` as the only special case, but you might want to do something different in your `__eq__`.

Of course "under the covers" this is very similar to just doing `sum(other == 0 and other is not False for other in a)`. But considering how `count()` is defined, it should come as no surprise that `a.count(x)` is similar to `sum(x == y for y in a)`.

You would only do this in the rare case where you have for some reason already decided to use `count` (perhaps because you're using some third-party code that's going to call it), and need to come up with a suitable object to pass it. Basically, it treats `count` as a function that calls an arbitrary function we write (requiring only that this function be the `__eq__` function of the argument) and counts the number of true return values. This is an accurate description of what `count` does, but not really the point of `count` since `sum` is more explicit.

Comment: Really liked the idea Steve. Just using `is` without `type` was considered unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

Many appropriate answers already given. Of course, an alternative is to filter the list on the type of the element you are querying for first.

```
>>> a = ["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]
>>> def count(li, item):
...     return list(filter(lambda x: type(x) == type(item), li)).count(item)
...
>>>
>>> count(a, 0)
10
>>> count(a, False)
1
>>> count(a, "a")
1
>>> class my_own_int(int): pass
...
>>> a.append(my_own_int(5))
>>> a.count(5)
1
>>> count(a, 5)
0
```

In case you are worried about the copy, you can use `sum` and abuse the fact we are trying to circumvent above (that `True == 1`).

```
def count(li, item):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x == item, filter(lambda x: type(x) == type(item), li)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run into that kind of problems frequently you can introduce the following class<sup>*</sup>

```
class Exactly:
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.value = something

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(self.value) == type(other) and self.value == other
```

and use it as follows:

```
a.count(Exactly(0))
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Of course you may need to enhance it for other operations too.