# str.upper() returns a string which apparently does not equal anything, including another str.upper()

Tags: python, string, uppercase

I've been trying to use Python's one function dedicated to making every letter in a string uppercase, but after using it on a string booleans don't work on that string. What do I mean you ask? Well let's just say the following booleans:

```
"b".upper() is "B"
".".upper() is "."
".".upper() is ".".upper()
```

are **all false**.

I'm so confused. It acts like after I convert a string to upper() form, instead of returning the same string with uppercase letters (which is what the documentation says it does), it returns a whole new object that doesn't equal anything even an object produced in the exact same conditions.

Setting breakpoints and looking at the actual values of the variables seems fruitless. I hover over `is_graduate_input = input("Enter (y/n)").upper()`
and it shows me a value of "Y", because that's what I entered. But then directly after that line my `print(is_graduate_input is "Y")` statement prints out False?!?! Why?!?!

The documentation for python says that their algorithm for making letters uppercase is described in some Unicode standard. I don't want to read through it. I don't think it will help. Can someone just please tell me what the hell is going on. I want to go to bed. I have school tomorrow.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) - it's a bad idea to use `is` for comparing with anything except singletons like `None`. Use `==`. Very similar to what happens in Java with `==` and `.equals()`.

Comment: @yeputons Is that my problem?!?! What should I be doing?

Comment: It is, you should use `==` in Python for comparing objects for equality. Do not use `is` outside of `is None` and `is not None` comparisons, unless you clearly understand what you're doing and why.

Comment: Did you try Googling Python string comparison?

Answer (score 1):

`is` will return `True` if two variables point to the same object id

`==` will return `True` if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.

What you are doing is comparing two different objects here and hence getting False.

```
"b".upper() is "B" # will return False
```

What will work for you is

```
"b".upper() == "B"  # will return True
```

Say you start with

```
a = "b"
b = "B"
print(id(a))
print(id(a)) # will print same id as above.
print(id(b))
print(id(b)) # will print same id as above.
```

output:

```
4337047792
4337047792
4337610568
4337610568
```

But if you print id for `a.upper()` it will return a new object each time and print a new id.

```
print(id(a.upper()))
print(id(a.upper()))
```

output:

```
4372772488
4372772376
```

This is the reason why `"b".upper() is "B" # will return False`. Because the id wont match.

you can read up more on these threads:

[why does comparing strings in python using either or is sometimes produce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

[understanding pythons is operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator)