# Python ID in same list not equal

Tags: python, list

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x

print(id(x))
print(id(y))
print(id(x) == id(y))
print(id(x) is id(y))
```

Output:

```
140181905497736
140181905497736
True
False
```

Why is the second one false when the id of x and y are the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's "is" operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this because in the first comparison you compare the identities of the two objects but in the second you compare the two new objects generated by the *id()* function. This example you help you understand better:

```
# Here you can see that a and b are indeed the same
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True

# Now lets store id(a) and id(b). Their values should still be the same
>>> A = id(a)
>>> A
4319687240
>>> B = id(b)
>>> B
4319687240
>>> A == B
True

# But A and B are separate objects. Which is what you compare in the second comparison 
>>> id(A)
4319750384
>>> id(B)
4319750544
>>> id(a) is id(b)
False
>>> A is B
False

# You can also see this at play if you try to print id of another id
>>> print(id(id(a)))
4319750416
>>> print(id(id(a)))
4319750512
```

Comment: Thank you, this explains it well!

Comment: @AlexVincent this is exactly what I said in my answer. Also it doesn't explain why the integers have different identities

Answer (score 1):

when you do `id(x) is id(y)` you're comparing the identities of the object's integer identities and not of the list objects themselves. As an implementation detail [integers are only cached in CPython in the range of `-5` to `256`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers). `id(x) == id(y)` does `return True` of course as expected because `x is y` `return`s `True`.