# How to compare an empty list and a list of string in python?

Tags: python

I have two lists, `data1` and `data2`:

```
data1 = [('hello world', [])]

data2 = [('hello world', 'greetings')]
```

I want to compare the values at the 2nd position of each list.

I am using the following piece of code to compare them, but it is printing only "a equals to c" but not "b equals to d" and it is printing the following result:

> "Value_a: hello world, Value_b: [],Value_c: hello world,Value_d: greetings"

```
for a,b in data1:
    for c,d in data2:
        print("Value_a: %s, Value_b: %s,Value_c: %s,Value_d: %s,"%(a,b,c,d))
        if a is c:
            print("a is equal to c")
            if b is d:
                print("b is equal to d")
                count+= 1
                print("Count = ",count)
```

Comment: Why *would* it print 'b equals to d'? In what way is an empty list equal to (or identical to, which is what you test with `is` - equality is `==`) the string `'greetings'`?

Comment: also, you have strings inside a tuple inside a list. The first element of `data1` is `('hello world', [])`, and there is no second element.

Comment: Check your indentation. `b is d` will only trigger if `a is c` also because of the indentation

Comment: You're already comparing the values in the second position accurately, since `[] != 'greetings'`. Can you clarify what you need to know?

Comment: And `if b is d` the program will throw `NamError` because `count` is not declared.

Comment: It looks like you want to pair items at the same index from each list. If so, `for d1, d2 in zip(data1, data2):print("'{}' is {}equal to '{}'".format(d1, ('' if d1==d2 else 'not '), d2)` works provided you change `data1` and `data2` to be lists of string and not lists of tuples of string.

Comment: If you only want to show when they are equal do `for d1, d2 in zip(data1, data2):if d1 == d2:print("'{}' is equal to '{}'".format(d1, d2)`

Answer (score 1):

> ...it is printing only `a equals to c` but not `b equals to d`...

1 - `b is d` **only executes** if `a is c` is `true`, you need to fix the indentation

2 - `is` will return `True` if two variables point to the same object, `==` if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.

---

You'll probably end-up with something like:

```
for a, b in data1:
    for c, d in data2:
        print("Value_a: %s, Value_b: %s,Value_c: %s,Value_d: %s," % (a, b, c, d))
        if a == c:
            print("a is equal to c")
        if b == d:
            print("b is equal to d")
            count += 1
            print("Count = ", count)
```

---

Note:

[Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use "==" instead of "is" ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: I was updating the answer when you commented. Tks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yours should work for your example, but to compare longer lists pairwise

```
for (a,b),(c,d) in zip(data1,data2):

    print("Value_a: %s, Value_b: %s,Value_c: %s,Value_d: %s,"%(a,b,c,d))
    if a is c:
        print("a is equal to c")
        if b is d:
            print("b is equal to d")
            count+= 1
            print("Count = ",count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to read this: [Understanding Python's "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator)

Besides, data2 contains two strings, meanwhile data1 contains one string and one empty lists.