# Why does `is` return False even though id's are identical?

Tags: python

I already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator#13650309) question, but I don't really get why the two `id()` calls return an identical value, while the `is` comparison returns `False`.

```python
>>> [2,2,2] + [1] == [2,2,2,1]
True
>>> [2,2,2] + [1] is [2,2,2,1]
False
>>> id([2,2,2] + [1])
4396847688
>>> id([2,2,2,1])
4396847688
```

To be sure, I did expect the two comparisons to return `True` and `False` as they did, I just don't get why the ids are not different.

Comment: Simply because the same memory is reused for the objects:  in the last two statements, the lifetimes of the objects whose id's you're obtaining do not overlap, so Python is free to (re)use the same memory for them.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! If it were an answer, I'd accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just re-entering my comment as "an answer":

Simply because the same memory is reused for the objects: in the last two statements, the lifetimes of the objects whose id's you're obtaining do not overlap, so Python is free to (re)use the same memory for them.