# String/unicode references in Python embedded dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question about the Python 2.7.5-Python 2.7.13.  It may be
about semantics or it may be a genuine Python bug.  I'm not entirely
sure which.  Here is the simplest code I can construct with the
issue

```
Python 2.7.13 |Enthought, Inc. (x86_64)| (default, Mar  2 2017, 08:20:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin

>>> dd = {'foo': {'yy':u'Tannenbaum'}}

>>> dd['foo']['yy'] is u'Tannenbaum'

False

>>> dd['foo']['yy'] == u'Tannenbaum'

True
```

Note: If 'Tannebaum' is changed from unicode to a string the outcome changes.  Both of the final tests are true.  The question is: Why do the two final tests differ in the unicode case?  My understanding is that since unicode and strings are both immutables the "is" and "==" tests should never differ in value.  But I get this behavior in both Python 2.7.13  and the old 2.7.5 that came installed on my Mac. Am I relying on something I shouldn't rely on? Is the moral that I should never use "is" for string equality?  But what is the principle that tells me that?

Postscript: I have access to a Python 3.6.2 on another machine, and lo and behold, I cannot reproduce this anomaly.

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 30 2017, 12:03:06) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> dd = {'foo': {'yy':u'Tannenbaum'}}

>>> dd['foo']['yy'] is u'Tannenbaum'
True

>>> dd['foo']['yy'] == u'Tannenbaum'
True
```

Comment: It's about string interning. `is` shouldn't be used for comparing strings. More info https://stackoverflow.com/a/25758019/1806780 Looks like Python 3 does interning in this case and 2 doesn't.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a little more educated about "is".