# python - password checker function always returning weak password

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, passwords, boolean

I've got a function in my script which gets an argument and compares it to some set variables to see whether the password is of suitable strength or not. Whenever I enter a password both suitable/unsuitable, it returns that the password is too weak. Code below:

```
def check_password(_passw):

    length = len(_passw) < 8
    num = re.search(r'\d', _passw) is None
    uppercase = re.search(r"[A-Z]", _passw) is None
    lowercase = re.search(r"[a-z]", _passw) is None

    suitable = not (length or num or uppercase or lowercase)

    if _passw is not suitable:
        print('Password weak, try again')
        sign_up()

    else:
        print('Password accepted')
```

Comment: Hint: `suitable` is a boolean: either `True` or `False`, but `_passw` is a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
if _passw is not suitable:
```

is too colloquial really. You mean

```
if not suitable:
```

edit:
The 'is' operator in python tests if 2 variables point to the same memory location (a.k.a. instance). It does not compare the values of these 2 variables. See for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator)

Comment: Yes, `_passw is not suitable` means that `_passw` and `suitable` are not references to the same object. Which they will never be.