# python: compare sliced string to string with "is" equals False

Tags: python

Comparing a sliced string with more than 1 character to another string with `is` equals `False`. See [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

But comparing only 1 character slices with `is` equals `True`. Why?

```
>>>> 'ab'[1:] is 'b'
True
>>>> 'abb'[1:] is 'bb'
False
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But why is the first equation `True`?

Comment: that, I don't know. might be that for single letters the difference is so small that the identities can overlap causing them to be the same. dunno. Perhaps Mr. Ryan can dedupe this based on this phenomenon!

Comment: I rephrased the question, so it focuses on the 1 character phenomen and could be de-duped. It would be interesting to see if anyone has an answer to that...

Comment: And I think I found the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Comment: I believe that answer (interning) is already included in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Ah, true. In one of the comments further on the bottom. OK, so let's keep this question as a duplicate. Thanks everyone!