# Why () is () returns True and (1,) is (1,) returns False?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

Been playing around with is and equality checks in Python. **None is None** returns **True**. My understanding is that there's only one **None** object at any point in the heap so every reference to **None** points to the same address. **[] is []** returns **False** since [] is mutable and there can exist more than one objects in the heap.**() is ()** also returns **True**. My explanation for this is that tuples are immutable so there's only one at any point in the heap. What I don't understand is why **(1,) is (1,)** returns **False**. Appreciate any response/corrections of my understanding.

Comment: "is" tests if its just a variable refers to the same object "identity" ie. x = (1,2,3); y = x; x is y will yield True. look here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650309/1400926

Comment: On reflection the dupe may not answer your question exactly, but it is certainly relevant

Comment: @EzzatA He understand that; his question is why two empty tuples have the same identity, where two empty lists or dictionaries do not.

Comment: @JohnGordon Aha.. ok sorry missed that.. on side note when checking id([]) every time it yields a different id.. while an empty tuple will yield the same id every time. so the is behaviour is explained.. i do not know the reason why however..

Comment: Thank you for the responses. as noted by John Gordon, my question is different to the one that has been marked as answered. I am interested in knowing why (1,) is (1,) is False.

Comment: @Thomas Your question is in spirit the exact same. If you read the answer on the linked duplicate, it should be clear why your check is False.

Comment: @miradulo You 're right, thank you and apologies for the duplicate.