# Python: assignment operator and double-equals in the same line

Tags: python

Is this allowed syntax?

```
for bit in binary_string:
    is_zero = bit == '0'
    ...
```

Edit: <strike>My IDE</strike> Python in terminal is throwing syntax error. I found it here: https://github.com/johnmee/codility/blob/master/ex-1-1-binarygap.py#L33

edit:

```
>>> N = 1004
>>> binary_string = str(bin(N))[2:]
>>> for bit in binary_string:
...     is = bit == '0'
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    is = bit == '0'
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: sure it is. This assigns `is_zero` the value of the operation `bit=="0"`, so if `bit` was `"0"` before, `is_zero` is now `True`. This is perfectly valid python.

What error is your IDE giving *exactly*?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the syntax, is_zero gets populated based on whether bit is equal to zero or not. It should work.

Comment: Check that you don't have an error further up your code, for example a missing single quote would detect an error on this line.  Could you please show the exact error message?

Comment: error message added

Comment: `is` is a python reserved word, rename the variable!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Comment: I'm going to downvote your question because you first said you used `is_zero` and then you showed you used `is`, which is a python keyword.  Inconsistency like that is not help to anyone trying to answer your question.

Comment: for future reference, it would be helpful if, when you have an error with your code, you actually posted the code that throws the error.

The original sample you posted was perfectly fine and you failed to mention that you'd changed it to create the error you were seeing. Had you posted your actual code (with the `is`) originally, your question would have been solved in seconds.

Comment: If you feel like `is` the variable name better suits here, then use `is_` to avoid confict with python keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is allowed, your problem is, that `is` is a reserved keyword, e.g.

```
foo is None
```

Rename your variable ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is legal because the right hand side of `=` is an *expression* which returns a value. In this case, the value `True` or `False`. After the expression has been evaluated, the name `is_zero` is assigned to that value.

Your `SyntaxError` is raised because you are trying to assign to the protected word `is`.