# Extract lines from text file using words as key from another text file

Tags: python

I am working on NLP and need to do some pre-processing of data.
I have two input files and have to generate an output file having intersection of those files where the first file acts as a key.

file 1 - contains list of words :

> aided
> from
> the
> poetry
> to

file 2 :

> the 0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.17862 -0.00066023 -0.6566 0.27843 -0.14767 -0.55677 0.14658 -0.0095095 0.011658 0.10204 -0.12792 -0.8443 -0.12181 -0.016801 -0.33279 -0.1552 -0.23131 -0.19181 -1.8823 -0.76746 0.099051 -0.42125 -0.19526 4.0071 -0.18594 -0.52287 -0.31681 0.00059213 0.0074449 0.17778 -0.15897 0.012041 -0.054223 -0.29871 -0.15749 -0.34758 -0.045637 -0.44251 0.18785 0.0027849 -0.18411 -0.11514 -0.78581
>
> of 0.70853 0.57088 -0.4716 0.18048 0.54449 0.72603 0.18157 -0.52393 0.10381 -0.17566 0.078852 -0.36216 -0.11829 -0.83336 0.11917 -0.16605 0.061555 -0.012719 -0.56623 0.013616 0.22851 -0.14396 -0.067549 -0.38157 -0.23698 -1.7037 -0.86692 -0.26704 -0.2589 0.1767 3.8676 -0.1613 -0.13273 -0.68881 0.18444 0.0052464 -0.33874 -0.078956 0.24185 0.36576 -0.34727 0.28483 0.075693 -0.062178 -0.38988 0.22902 -0.21617 -0.22562 -0.093918 -0.80375
>
> to 0.68047 -0.039263 0.30186 -0.17792 0.42962 0.032246 -0.41376 0.13228 -0.29847 -0.085253 0.17118 0.22419 -0.10046 -0.43653 0.33418 0.67846 0.057204 -0.34448 -0.42785 -0.43275 0.55963 0.10032 0.18677 -0.26854 0.037334 -2.0932 0.22171 -0.39868 0.20912 -0.55725 3.8826 0.47466 -0.95658 -0.37788 0.20869 -0.32752 0.12751 0.088359 0.16351 -0.21634 -0.094375 0.018324 0.21048 -0.03088 -0.19722 0.082279 -0.09434 -0.073297 -0.064699 -0.26044
>
> and 0.26818 0.14346 -0.27877 0.016257 0.11384 0.69923 -0.51332 -0.47368 -0.33075 -0.13834 0.2702 0.30938 -0.45012 -0.4127 -0.09932 0.038085 0.029749 0.10076 -0.25058 -0.51818 0.34558 0.44922 0.48791 -0.080866 -0.10121 -1.3777 -0.10866 -0.23201 0.012839 -0.46508 3.8463 0.31362 0.13643 -0.52244 0.3302 0.33707 -0.35601 0.32431 0.12041 0.3512 -0.069043 0.36885 0.25168 -0.24517 0.25381 0.1367 -0.31178 -0.6321 -0.25028 -0.38097

The output that I want in a new file (file 3) should be :

> the 0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.17862 -0.00066023 -0.6566 0.27843 -0.14767 -0.55677 0.14658 -0.0095095 0.011658 0.10204 -0.12792 -0.8443 -0.12181 -0.016801 -0.33279 -0.1552 -0.23131 -0.19181 -1.8823 -0.76746 0.099051 -0.42125 -0.19526 4.0071 -0.18594 -0.52287 -0.31681 0.00059213 0.0074449 0.17778 -0.15897 0.012041 -0.054223 -0.29871 -0.15749 -0.34758 -0.045637 -0.44251 0.18785 0.0027849 -0.18411 -0.11514 -0.78581
>
> to 0.68047 -0.039263 0.30186 -0.17792 0.42962 0.032246 -0.41376 0.13228 -0.29847 -0.085253 0.17118 0.22419 -0.10046 -0.43653 0.33418 0.67846 0.057204 -0.34448 -0.42785 -0.43275 0.55963 0.10032 0.18677 -0.26854 0.037334 -2.0932 0.22171 -0.39868 0.20912 -0.55725 3.8826 0.47466 -0.95658 -0.37788 0.20869 -0.32752 0.12751 0.088359 0.16351 -0.21634 -0.094375 0.018324 0.21048 -0.03088 -0.19722 0.082279 -0.09434 -0.073297 -0.064699 -0.26044

The following code runs without any error but the ouput file that I am getting is empty :

```
f1 = open('input_key.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('input_file.txt', 'r')
f3 = open('output_file.txt', 'w')

for word in f1.readlines():
    for line in f2.readlines():
        if word is line.strip().split()[0]:     
            f3.write(line)

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

I am unable to understand what is wrong here. Any help appreciated.
file2 and file3 have no extra lines in between. I just added those to make the question readable.

UPDATE 
Thanks to the comments, I got to know that the if statement is evaluating to false. Any way to overcome this or other alternatives to perform my task ?

Comment: are u sure your code reaches `f3.write(line)`

Comment: I'd `strip` word as well just to be safe, but my guess is your if statement is evaluating false

Comment: print everything, and debug step by step. find where the error exactly is

Comment: When I run this, I'm getting an IndexError at the `if` statement...

Comment: @emsimpson92 tried it with `strip` but still the file is empty

Comment: @Adi219, yes i saw the moment i posted the comment that he already used `split()` - i was misreading it as a single `strip()` so i deleted it

Comment: I checked it, the if statement is evaluating false. Any ideas how to correct it or an alternative way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want it to do:

```
f1 = open('input_key.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('input_file.txt', 'r')
f3 = open('output_file.txt', 'a')

for word in f1.readlines():
    for line in f2.readlines():
        if line != '\n' and word.strip() == line.strip().split()[0]:
            f3.write(line)
    f2.seek(0)

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

You need to reset the cursor position for `readlines` at the end of each loop with `f2.seek(0)`

I would also open the `output_file.txt` as `a` (append), You can Delete the `output_file.txt` at the beginning of the script to clear it out each time you run it with:

```
import os
os.remove("output_file.txt")
```

I would also do `==` instead of `is`, `is` will test if two object are the same, not if something equals something else

EDIT: I would look at wiesion's answer below about `list comprehension` for some tips on writing cleaner code

Comment: Thank you. This is working. Though I am unable to understand how. Could you please elaborate more on the if statement ?

Comment: Just added more context, but `line.strip().split()[0]` returns a `string` so you would need to use `==` to see if 2 `strings` equal` each other. `is` will check to see if 2 `objects` are the same. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Comment: eh, took the `f2.seek(0)` from my answer instead of re-opening for each word? ;) Anyways it's not just about cleaner code, it is also about avoiding unnecessary nested loops (and filtering out empty rows, which turns out not be the case here).

Comment: Yeah I took the `seek`, it much better than closing and opening the file over and over.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `is` is the identity operator, checking if 2 elements are the same identity

`==` is equality logic operator

```
if word is line.strip().split()[0]:
```

Change it to

```
if word == line.strip().split()[0]:
```

Comment: Tried that. Still not working. I actually came to `is` after `==` !

Comment: Might not have solved it, but this definitely wasn't doing you any favors

Comment: Yes, that was the second issue after not doing a `f2.seek(0)`

Answer (score 2):

I just copied your files and wrote the code as i would do if i was given your requirements:

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as word_file:
    words = [word.strip() for word in word_file.read().splitlines() if word.strip()]

with open("feed.txt", "r") as feed_file:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in feed_file.read().splitlines() if line.strip()]

with open('result.txt', 'w') as result_file:
    result_file.write("\n".join([line for line in lines if line.split()[0] in words]))
```

Of course i am doing quite some [list comprehensions](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) here to avoid all the nested loops.

If your word and input files are large, then you should avoid reading the entire file into memory with comprehensions (Thanks @Bayko for the reminder) and you should switch to:

```
words = []
with open("words.txt", "r") as word_file:
    # This reads the words file line by line instead of reading the entire file
    for word in word_file:
        word = word.strip()
        if word:
            words.append(word)

with open('result.txt', 'w') as result_file:
    with open("feed.txt", "r") as feed_file:
        # This reads the input file line by line instead of reading the entire file
        for line in feed_file:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                continue
            if line.split()[0] in words:
                result_file.write(line + "\n")
```

Also when i run your code locally:

> ```
> if word is line.strip().split()[0]:
> ```
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

This error happens because of empty lines - but most of all, you are stuck with `f2.readlines()` - you never do a `f2.seek(0)` to reset the position and `==` is not the same as `is` (See @Atterson's answer). Fixing those issues in your code it would look like:

```
f1 = open('words.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('feed.txt', 'r')
f3 = open('result.txt', 'w')

for word in f1.readlines():
    word = word.strip()
    if not word:
        continue
    for line in f2.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        if word == line.split()[0]:
            f3.write(line + "\n")
    f2.seek(0)

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

With both scripts my `result.txt` looks like

> the 0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.17862 -0.00066023 -0.6566 0.27843 -0.14767 -0.55677 0.14658 -0.0095095 0.011658 0.10204 -0.12792 -0.8443 -0.12181 -0.016801 -0.33279 -0.1552 -0.23131 -0.19181 -1.8823 -0.76746 0.099051 -0.42125 -0.19526 4.0071 -0.18594 -0.52287 -0.31681 0.00059213 0.0074449 0.17778 -0.15897 0.012041 -0.054223 -0.29871 -0.15749 -0.34758 -0.045637 -0.44251 0.18785 0.0027849 -0.18411 -0.11514 -0.78581
>
> to 0.68047 -0.039263 0.30186 -0.17792 0.42962 0.032246 -0.41376 0.13228 -0.29847 -0.085253 0.17118 0.22419 -0.10046 -0.43653 0.33418 0.67846 0.057204 -0.34448 -0.42785 -0.43275 0.55963 0.10032 0.18677 -0.26854 0.037334 -2.0932 0.22171 -0.39868 0.20912 -0.55725 3.8826 0.47466 -0.95658 -0.37788 0.20869 -0.32752 0.12751 0.088359 0.16351 -0.21634 -0.094375 0.018324 0.21048 -0.03088 -0.19722 0.082279 -0.09434 -0.073297 -0.064699 -0.26044

Comment: Your list comprehension approach is not optimal. What you are doing is storing the entire array in memory which in this case I guess is ok and makes for a cleaner code. However, if the files are big in size you will have to use fseek

Comment: Fair enough - i will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have three new lines in your second file. You need to perform a check on your array after you split it to check whether it has any elements or not. That solves the problem. Or do a try catch with IndexError and you should be good

Comment: The array has the elements. The strings that the if statement is comparing are there. I checked by printing them separately. But still the statement evaluates to false !!

Comment: @user129129 Which checks are you using?

Comment: @Adi219 Tried both `is` & `==`

Comment: You need to close your 2nd file since read takes the cursor to the end of the file and doesnt start again.