# tuple of value and identity are same but identity testing (is) get false in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> t=(1,2,3)
>>> t+t
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
>>> t*2
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
>>> t+t==t*2
True
>>> t+t is t*2
False
>>> id(t+t)
49172744L
>>> id(t*2)
49172744L
```

but they also have same id (t+t),(t*2). Why are they not equal

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Comment: `is` does identity testing, `==` tests for equality.. You and your twin might seem equal, but you are not identical. same goes for `t+t` and `t*2` - they look equal but are not identical

Comment: >>> id(t+t)
    49172744L
    >>> id(t*2)
    49172744L