# why does input() return a different object id regardless of what is entered?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does input() not return a constant id for strings?

```
>>> id(input())
String
2339026478168
>>> id(input())
String
2339026478224
```

This is compared to creating 2 strings of the same value:

```
>>> id('String')
2339026468680
>>> id('String')
2339026468680
```

This directly impacts the [`is`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator) operator

Comment: Don't use `'is'`, you don't even have any guarantee that 2 identical string literals have the same `id`. Use `==`.

Comment: And why should it? Are all people named Michael the same person?

Comment: @Julien my question is less "why should it" but more "Why does it?"

Answer (score -1):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is
>   guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its
>   lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same
>   id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in
>   memory.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#id

There are situations that some values have the same id, because they are implemented as singletons. These are usually values that are statistically going to occur often in a typical program. Some obvious examples of this are None, True, and False.

```
>>> variable = True
>>> variable is True
True
```

Some non-obvious examples of this are relatively small numbers.

```
>>> variable = 256
>>> variable is 256
True
>>> variable = 257
>>> variable is 257
False
```

This is also why people advise using the `==` operator over `is` for value comparison.

Comment: My question was more regarding why input() doesn't construct the id the same way every time.

Comment: @Apc0243 Input doesn't "construct" the id. If you have carefully read the answer you will know it.

Comment: I don't have a great understanding of all the Python internals, but I'll hazard to guess anyways. It might be because a literal variable assignment, ie `var = 'string'`, gives the same id and `input()` doesn't because the former is a constant/literal string and input can be anything. This is just speculation, so please take it with a grain of salt

Comment: @pkqxdd my question was less to do with how `id()` is executed, and more why a string of equal value is associated with the same id while the same string from input() is not. My best guess is that on creation of a string value the memory address is established and checked each time while input() has no ability to reference that address? So every time input() produces a new object, regardless of its value, while strings created of the same value through more traditional pythonic means don't have this issue? I apologize if this is obvious, I just don't really understand