# python string comparison fail

Tags: python, string, comparison

I just stumbled on what seems a bug to me :

```
var = "2"
if var is "" or "1":
    print(var)
```

This piece of code returns "2" as I expect it to print nothing.

Can someone explains this result to me ?

Tested on 2.7 and 3.4

Comment: It may help to understand that this is parsed as `if ((var is "") or ("1"))` so you need to understand how `is` works and what the meaning of `"1"` is when considered as a boolean

Comment: `is` operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Comment: See truth value testing here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=type%20conversions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your expression is parsed as `(var is "") or "1"`, which is always True, because `"1"`is True-ish.
2. If you add parentheses to get `var is ("" or "1")`, that is equvalent to `var is True`, because `"" or "1"` is True, because "1" is True-ish.
3. Comparing strings with `is` is fraught with peril, because the `is` operator checks *identity*, not equality.

You probably want `var in ("", "1")`

Comment: Yes, obvious mistake from me, I shall pay more attention next time... Thank you for the answer anyway !