# Why does np.all return the wrong value when I use "is" compared to "=="?

Tags: python, numpy

So I tracked down a bug in my code and can reproduce is with the following. Basically I need to check if all elements in an `np.ndarray` are not 0.

```
>>> a = np.ones((3,3))
>>> np.all(a == 0) == False
True
```

Okay perfect, all values within `a` are non-zero. I know I can also do `np.all((a == 0) == False)` instead to explicitly ask to be compared to 0 but I didn't at first and this is made me realize there is a difference when comparing `is` to `==` in the `False` case.

```
>>> np.all(a == 0) is False
False
```

I know that `is` should compare if the objects point to the same object. But does this mean that my two values that returned `False` don't actually point to the same `False`? I may just be overthinking this though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type is `numpy.bool_` rather than `bool`:

```
In [11]: type(np.all(a == 0))
Out[11]: numpy.bool_

In [12]: type(False)
Out[12]: bool
```

The `is` check asserts that two objects point to the [same object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650309/1240268).

Comment: This [github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5942) seems to confirm the reason: the difference is indeed because the class is efferent.

Comment: Dang, I thought `np.all` was returning the same type as the `all` I'm used to. Should have checked that first. Thanks!

Comment: @Chrispresso, you shouldn't be using `is` even with "the `all` I'm used to" - it's not testing what you actually want to test.  About the only common, valid use for this operator is `X is None`.