# Python3 “is” operator outside of small_ints

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm using Python 3.7.4 and understand the small integers are numbers [-5,256].

I want to know why the result of #2 in the code below returns `True`. Shouldn't it be `False`?

```py
#1
b=257
c=257
b=b+1
c=c+1
print(id(b))
print(id(c))
print(b is c)

#2
b1=257
c1=257
print(id(b1))
print(id(c1))
print(b1 is c1)

Result in Visual Code Terminal
4306256464
4306256432
False
4306256240
4306256240
True
```

Here's my code in Mac Terminal, which I think is the ideal result

```py
Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b=257
>>> c=257
>>> print(id(b))
4351554224
>>> print(id(c))
4351554096
>>> print(b is c)
False
```

Reference:
[1]["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Comment: Post all relevant code and output here directly as text.

Comment: The is operator checks for object instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650309/362792

Comment: Please take a look at how to use markdown format for posting code.

Comment: Python 3.7.5 on Linux returns `False` on both cases.

Comment: Since you have now changed your question to a slightly different one, I have added another link which answers that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Python instantiates and interns the range of numbers -5 to 256 inclusive all of which will be singleton objects.
Python creates a single object for all the variables which have the same value between -5 to 256

Read [Singletons and interning in Python](https://medium.com/@daniel.tooke/singletons-and-interning-in-python-328413db334).

Comment: Also, please post the code here instead of an image.

Comment: The *CPython* implementation interns small integers; the language Python says nothing about whether an implementation must or must not do any such interning.