# Confused with usage of "is int" in Python 3.7

Tags: python, int

I've just run into an issue with Python 3.7 in Spyder console that confused me.

Why does `s is int` return `False`, while `type(s)` returns `int`?

```
s = 2

s is int
Out[310]: False

type(s)
Out[311]: int
```

Comment: Because `2` is not the `int` class, but an _instance_ of this class. In the same vein, `"hello" is str` will be `False`. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Comment: Because the *type* of `s` `is int`, not `s` itself (the value).

Comment: I think you are looking for `>>> isinstance(2, int)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Python's "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator)