# Python's special treatment to certain integers. Why?

Tags: python

I came across this phrase:

> "Python keeps an array of ints between `-5` and `256`. When you create
>   an int in that range, you get a reference to a pre-existing object"

You can verify with this code:

```
def check(n,d):  
    a = b = n     
    a -= d
    b -= d 
    return a is b
```

Now, `check(500,10)` returns `False`. But `check(500,300)` returns `True`. Why does Python compiler would do such a thing? Isn't it a perfect recipe for bugs?

Comment: No it's not a "perfect recipe" because you should *never* be using `is` to compare integers.

Comment: what kind of bugs are you foreseeing? ints are immutable anyways...

Comment: Integers are immutable

Comment: It is not a recipe for bug, but it is a good question I think. Python choses when to reassign an int internally to point to a different memory address/value. Altho your a/b values are always the same, their `id()` might not be! So I would recommend you adding `print(id(a), id(b))` to see what is happening and do not use `is`for comparison (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter

Comment: The "bug" only occurs when erroneously using the *identity* operator instead of the *equality* operator. Using ``is`` instead of ``==`` is the bug already, not the implementation defined result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPython (the reference interpreter) does it because it saves a lot of memory (and a small amount of execution time) to have the most commonly used `int`s served from a cache. Incrementing a number uses a shared temporary, not a unique value in each place you do the increment. Iterating a `bytes` or `bytearray` object can go *much* faster by directly pulling the cached entries. It's not a language guarantee though, so never write code like this (which relies on it).

It's not a bug factory because:

1. Relying on object identity tests for `int`s is a terrible idea in the first place; you should always be using `==` to compare `int`s, and
2. `int`s are immutable; it's impossible to modify the cached entries without writing intentionally evil `ctypes` or C extension modules. Normal Python code can't trigger bugs due to this cache.

Comment: " is a terrible idea" -> "is just plain wrong"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Por qué no los dos? :-)