# Why is this statement false in python 3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, conditional-statements, comparison

`8 is int`
The above line of code statement shows false.
Even though 8 is an int.
How does this work?
I would like to know how is operator works in this case.
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Comment: Use `isinstance()`.

Comment: As you said 8 is **an** int, but 8 is not int, because int is a type, and 8 is an instance of this type.

Comment: Are you identical to the concept of being human? No; you *are a* human - i.e., you are a member of the set of humans, or you are an instance of humanity. `is` does not do the kind of test you want. In programming, we need to be precise about language, in a way that is difficult or impossible in English.

Answer (score 0):

just a small mistake in your syntax. You should have written `type(8) is int` in your condition statement which is the correct syntax. `type(object)` returns the class of the object so you can compare it with the is operator. So for example:-

`Bonjour` is an object of class `Greeting`

So the following code:-

```
if type(Bonjour) is Greeting:
    print("Bonjour is a Greeting!")
```

would print out:-

```
Bonjour is a Greeting
```