# Python 'is' operator for two long strings

Tags: python, string-comparison, python-internals, string-interning

```
a = 'This is a very long string. This is a very long string. No?'
b = 'This is a very long string. This is a very long string. No?'

print(id(a), id(b))
print(a is b)
```

On my computer, the results are:

```
4467772080 4467772080
True
```

As I know Python only caches short strings. But why such a long string, it still keeps only one copy? In fact, I changed it to be a very long string (even longer than 1024), **a** and **b** are still pointing to the same string object. Please correct me where I am wrong?

Comment: try it in the shell instead of in a script... when they are in the same file python will cache this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator The answer with 61 upvotes has the information you are looking for

Comment: Strings are immutable, so Python is free to share them or not as it sees fit.  I wouldn't spend too much effort trying to understand what happens under the covers.

Comment: `(a is b) == False` in my interpreter Py3.9.1 with the exact same string. The point is: what you claim doesn't always happen, and therefore if you're looking for any strange undocumented rule about interning-- it doesn't exist.

Comment: What is it you don't understand? The runtime is free to intern immutable objects. There *are no rules or guarantees about this*. What's probably happening here is that you have to immutable string literals being cached in the same block.

Comment: @JoranBeasley both Pycharm and command line, a and b are still pointing to the same object, but in interactive mode, they are different, where only a single word would be cached.

Comment: So when there are no guarantees, many textbooks illustrate **is** operator with this example...

Comment: @Vincent In that case you should avoid those textbooks because the authors don't know  Python