# is operator with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.DataFrame({
'name' : ['o', 'a', 'x'],
'mark' : [7, 4, 10]
})
```

Why does it return `False` when I write
`dt.iloc[1] is dt.iloc[1]` or `dt.iloc[1,2] is dt.iloc[1,2]` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-the-is-operator)

Comment: Because those two expressions evaluate to different objects. The `is` operator tests for object identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `equals` method to compare `Series` data in `pandas` also you can refer [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.equals.html#:%7E:text=Compare%20two%20Series%20objects%20of,Series%20is%20equal%2C%20False%20otherwise.&text=Compare%20two%20DataFrame%20objects%20of,DataFrame%20is%20equal%2C%20False%20otherwise.) Here!

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.DataFrame({
'name' : ['o', 'a', 'x'],
'mark' : [7, 4, 10]
})

dt.iloc[1].equals(dt.iloc[1])
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 1):

`dt.iloc[1]` creates a Series that is a *copy* of the original, so you're asking if two different things you create are the same thing, which they are not.

If I do:

```
x = dt.iloc[1]
print(x is x)

y = dt.iloc[1]
print(x is y)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

See Bhavya's answer for how to properly compare Series.