# python: difference between != and <>?

Tags: python, operators, comparison-operators

So, I'm making a python cheat sheet for myself, and when I started covering comparison operators, I noticed these two:

```
a = 1
b = 2

if a != b:
 print("Dunno")

if a <> b:
 print("Dunno")
```

I'm using python 2.7 and was curious if there's a difference between the two operators?

Comment: This is a dupe, but Google and Stack Overflow search suck at finding these operators.

Comment: I am no expert in Python but in SQL they are nearly identical. <> is considered language specific to MySQL as it is not standardized accross the board. I would just use "!="

Comment: Yeah, lots of information on the operators, but I couldn't find the difference between them; which makes sense, seeing as there isn't one :P Thanks guys

edit: Save for currency

Comment: See [this question on is-there-a-not-equal-operator-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060506/is-there-a-not-equal-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

As described in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in), they are the same.  `<>` is deprecated and was removed in Python 3, so you should use `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

`<>` is deprecated. Other than that, no.