# I don't know what is wrong with my syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, quote

Here's my code;

```
def save(name):
    if x['fname'] == 'ply.json':
        save1(name)
    elif x['fname'] not 'ply.json':
        write_data({'fname':'ply.json', 'name':'Karatepig'}, 'ply.json')
```

I get an error stating that I have this syntax error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 4
  elif x['fname'] not 'ply.json':
                               ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question should be closed because it is predicated on a typo and will have no utility for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`something not something` is not a valid expression. If you want to test if it is not equal, use `!=`:

```
elif x['fname'] != 'ply.json':
```

However, since this is the exact opposite of the preceding `if` test, just use `else` here:

```
if x['fname'] == 'ply.json':
    save1(name)
else:
    write_data({'fname':'ply.json', 'name':'Karatepig'}, 'ply.json')
```

Comment: Thanks again, you're so fast in your answers, heh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `!=` to test inequality, like this:

```
    elif x['fname'] != 'ply.json':
```

But why use `elif`?

```
def save(name):
    if x['fname'] == 'ply.json':
        save1(name)
    else:
        write_data({'fname':'ply.json', 'name':'Karatepig'}, 'ply.json)
```

Comment: Using else for something else later. Thanks though.

Comment: @Karatepig but there isn't any other else. The thing is either equal, or it isn't.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm going to use else to check for an "invalid" fname and change it to one that I'm considering "valid".

Comment: But it will never arrive there, since one of the first two conditions will always be true.

Comment: @Kara Daniel was trying to say that it can only either be equal or not equal, so it will never reach the `else` because it can't be equal and not equal at the same time.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Oh I see. You're right. I apologise.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`!=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060506/is-there-a-not-equal-operator-in-python) for "not equal":

```
elif x['fname'] != 'ply.json':
```