# Is there a difference between != and <> operators in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

I tried searching, but could not find much about the `<>` operator.

*[Python - Basic Operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)* mentions that `<>` is "similar" to the `!=` operator and does not say what is different or how it is different.

My tests seem to show it is the same:

```
a = 2, b = 3
>>> a != b
True
>>> a <> b
True
>>> b = 2
>>> a != b
False
>>> a <> b
False
```

Comment: `<>` is deprecated and removed in python 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060506/is-there-a-not-equal-operator-in-python

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators) says that they are equivalent.

> The comparison operators `<>` and `!=` are alternate spellings of the same operator. `!=` is the preferred spelling; `<>` is obsolescent.

The `<>` operator has been *removed* from Python 3.

Comment: ...and `<>` isn't mentioned in the [v3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators) at all.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: Thanks for the clarification about the 2.x and 3.x difference as well.

Comment: you can still use it Python 3: 
`from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL`

Comment: Any one know the historical reason for including <> as "not equal" in the first place? Never have I seen this operator before, in math or programming.

Comment: @NoName: Pascal uses <> as not equal operator, and it is simply a concatenation of lower and greater operator. You may read it as *lower or greater than*. This is in the context of Pascal equivalent to not equals. Many SQL dialects support both operators, too.