# not able to guess the invalid syntax in the programe

Tags: python, python-3.x

stars must be printed at the positions i have used but invalid syntax error is coming

```
# printing star in a heart shape format
for row in range(0,6):
    for colu in range(0,7):
        if row==0 and colu%3!==0:
            print('*',end=='')
        elif row==1 and colu%3==0:
            print('*',end=='')
        elif row-colu==2:
            print('*',end=='')
        elif row+colu==8:
            print('*',end=='')
        else:
            print(' ',end=='')
```

Comment: `!==` should be `!=` in the `if` statement.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11060508/1978785

Comment: For future reference, you should include the specific error text. It saves a ton of time in figuring out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

replace if row==0 and colu%3!==0 by

```
if row==0 and colu%3!=0
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to replace `!==` with `!=`. However, you also need to change `end==` to `end=`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if row==0 and colu%3!==0:
```

Should be like this:

```
if row == 0 and colu % 3 != 0:
```

And all of the `end==`, should be in the form `end=`

So all together:

```
for row in range(0, 6):
    for colu in range(0, 7):
        if row == 0 and colu % 3 != 0:
            print('*', end='')
        elif row == 1 and colu % 3 == 0:
            print('*', end='')
        elif row - colu == 2:
            print('*', end='')
        elif row + colu == 8:
            print('*', end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')
```

Comment: While I agree that `!==` should be `!=` and `end==` should be `end=`, it is not strictly necessary to have whitespace in between operators. `if row==0 and colu%3!=0:` is valid syntax, albeit not idiomatically styled.

Comment: @Kevin very true, that's why I didn't say that the lack of whitespace was a problem. I just habitually corrected the code to have cleaner whitespace usage.