# Don't understand the use of x != " "

Tags: python, palindrome

Hello I'm new coding and I have one doubt about a problem that ask me to compare an input string and define if is a palindrome or not. I've read about some answers but I'm not sure why they use some parts.
In this code:

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    ns = ""
    rv = ""
    input_string =input_string.lower()

    for x in input_string:
        **if x!=" ":**
        ns =ns+ x
        rs = x+rs
    # Compare the strings
    if ns==rs:
        return True
    return False
```

The part of the code that is **if x!=" ":** is the part I don't get it. I understand that the for loop allow us to place us in each letter of the input script but if it's a space the character in the script what happen?

Comment: This means if the value of X isnt a space or “ “

Comment: ... *They* must have had a specification that excluded spaces when evaluating palindromeness - the spaces don't count in their definition of a palindrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "not equal" operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060506/is-there-a-not-equal-operator-in-python)

Comment: Ok, I get it now. We're just evaluating if the string is Palindrome and we're not including the space. Thanks!!!!